# Embedding a CGRect in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, cgrect

Is it possible to embed a CGRect into a navigation bar just like this screenshot: [here](http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa42/mininukinfuts/IMG_0005.png)

I've done this:

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[self.view addSubview:aView];
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, -15, 150, 10)];
```

Using a negative figure, it actually allows me to place the label in the same space as the nav bar, but it will be hidden behind it. Is there way for me to bring the label to the front (change the z-index?)? Or is there a way to embed a label in the nav bar?

I've tried using this code but it doesn't effect the label:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:aView];
```

Answered thanks to EmptyStack:

Adding this code:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = aView;
 [aView addSubview:title];
```

Allows to embed the title (or more) in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this one.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = aView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what i'm trying to do is embed 3 labels into the nav bar, just like in the screenshot i posted. titleView only provides one label afaik

Comment: You can add any view as the *titleView*, not just an *UILabel*. Create a *UIView*. Add three *UILables* into the *UIView*. Set the *UIView* as the *titleView*.

Comment: thanks, i know how to create the three labels, but how would i set the UIView as the titleView? (something like self.view.titleView?)

Comment: Got it:   self.navigationItem.titleView = aView;
     [aView addSubview:title];

I'll update my question with the answer. Thanks :)